# how to open whatsapp home screen from my app using intents

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I'm using the following code:

```
openWhatsApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "launch whatsapp");
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
});
```

Thereby I get this error and I'm not able to open WhatsApp:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getFlags()' on a null object reference
```

What might go wrong and how could I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you that I will describe here.

1. Edit `manifest.xml` like this:

```xml
<manifest
    ...
    >
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

2. Put those code in your button click.

```java
String PACKAGE_WHATSAPP = "com.whatsapp";
if (isPackageExisted(PACKAGE_WHATSAPP)) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE_WHATSAPP);
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you don't have whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

3. The method is will be help you in check package exist or not in your device.

```java
public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Main"));
startActivity(intent);
```